# How can I add a Word to Windows 10 Auto-Correct?

Tags: windows, windows-10, spell-check, autocorrect

Windows 10 has added an Auto-Correct feature for typing. I want to be able to edit the dictionary. [This document](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25994-spell-checking-dictionary-add-remove-words-windows-10-a.html) says that I should be able to find it here:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Spelling\<language tag>\default.acl

I've found it, but it's just an empty file. How do I edit this thing?

Comment: Protip:  it **is** there on my Windows 10 machines, both my x86 laptop and my x64 desktop.  That being said, I haven't heard of anything that leads me to believe that you can add words to that `default.acl` file, but hopefully someone else has.

Comment: Ugh. I stand corrected, I looked in default not my username. Thanks. I'll update.

Comment: Hi Jonathan Mee - please check my edit to my question which explains how to edit the acl file. I hope this answers your question and solves your problem.

Comment: @micstr Oh thanks for reminding me. I meant to accept it after I tested it but forgot to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this out from: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25994-spell-checking-dictionary-add-remove-words-windows-10-a.html

They document two ways to do it.

1. Add highlighted misspelled words with right click "Add to dictionary"
2. Add or Remove Words in Spell Checking Dictionary default.dic file for a Language

   Here you put word in the  %AppData%\Microsoft\Spelling right dictionary for your language. Open the default.dic file with Notepad. Put word in plaintext. One per row.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

For auto correct you add words in the `default.acl` directory as " autocorrect pair with the words separated by a vertical bar ("|") (in the AutoCorrect word list)" (See Microsoft page [dictionary files section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748(v=vs.85).aspx)).

For example, if you wanted to change misspelling *mnger* to *manager*, then you would add this line in .acl file:

```
mnger|manager
```

I tested it now. I had no spaces between words and the pipe.

Plus, please make sure "Autocorrect misspelled words" is on in Settings.

Comment: I don't think this does help. It doesn't have anything to do with Auto-Correct does it?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan I was not clear enough. I have added details on the autocorrect, add line "misspeltword|goodword" to your acl file

Answer (score 0):

For MS Word, go to the search bar and type "Language Preference". Select the "Proofing" section, Click the "Auto correct Options" button. Under "Replace text as you type", delete the text you do not want Word to auto correct.

Or add words you want to auto correct.