# How to Add Dictionaries of Text Suggestions to Windows 10 Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, autocorrect, on-screen-keyboard

In Windows 10 in recent versions, an option has been added to predict text and correct errors

This option exists only in English, but not in my language

I tried to search the source of the English language dictionary to add words in my language, and I did not find

I saw the post written [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1171667/how-can-i-add-a-word-to-windows-10-auto-correct), and tried it, I even added a folder in the name of my language, (by its nickname), and did not help.

I also searched Google, and did not find anyone who thought of a similar idea.

I will be happy to help, or get directions to look for